# How far is this statement likely to be true, "the way what can be measured almost always takes precedence over what cannot"?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, semantics, subjectivity, capitalism

Excerpt from Rebecca Solnit's book 'Men Explain Things to Me':

> My friend Chip Ward speaks of “the tyranny of the quantifiable,” of
> the way what can be measured almost always takes precedence over what
> cannot: private profit over public good; speed and efficiency over
> enjoyment and quality; the utilitarian over the mysteries and meanings that
> are of greater use to our survival and to more than our survival, to lives that
> have some purpose and value that survive beyond us to make a civilization
> worth having.
> The tyranny of the quantifiable is partly the failure of language and
> discourse to describe more complex, subtle, and fluid phenomena, as well
> as the failure of those who shape opinions and make decisions to
> understand and value these slipperier things. It is difficult, sometimes even
> impossible, to value what cannot be named or described, and so the task of
> naming and describing is an essential one in any revolt against the status
> quo of capitalism and consumerism. Ultimately the destruction of the Earth
> is due in part, perhaps in large part, to a failure of the imagination or to its
> eclipse by systems of accounting that can’t count what matters.

Comment: And the question is??? Current (Western?) world is massively "quantified" in the sense that it is driven by numbers: from finance to daily life. This is a fact. Is this bad or good? Maybe neither....

Comment: "It is difficult, sometimes even impossible, to value what cannot be named or described, ..." Correct albeit trivial: if we cannot "name" it, how can we discuss/understand it? But "description" does not necessarily means "measuring": see art.

Comment: "...and so the task of naming and describing is an essential one in any revolt against the status quo of capitalism and consumerism." But what is the logical connection with the firs part? Again, only the trivial assertion that in order to fight against capitalism we have to understand it, i.e. to study economic and social facts, history etc?

Comment: "Ultimately the destruction of the Earth is due in part, perhaps in large part, to a failure of the imagination or to its eclipse by systems of accounting that can’t count what matters." Again a commonplace and reasonably true assertion: modern "finance-driven" world has lost contact with "values". Already said many many times; see e.g. [Ezra Pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra_Pound).

Comment: it's one paragraph, don't be too harsh about it being trivial out of context imho @MauroALLEGRANZA we often, as readers, pull out the most salient points to start with

Comment: Many things can be quantified if you try hard enough - you can survey people to get a quantitative measure of happiness (such a survey may have a whole lot of problems, but it's something, at least). Other things may be objected to even though they aren't explicitly quantified - e.g. utilitarianism alludes to quantification, but things often aren't concretely quantified, outside of like-vs-like comparisons. The tyranny of the unquantifiable may be to appeal to believing things because they "feel good", even though we have no good reason for believing that they *are* good, never mind true.

Comment: The claim seems intuitively correct and insightful to me. But I don't think "how far is it likely to be true" is answerable here. Ironically, it's not the sort of thing you can quantify. Perhaps you're proving the point by even asking.

Answer (score 1):

Any question that begins "how likely" sounds a question of probability. How likely is probability applicable to determining a claim is meaningful in some contexts and not others and depends on which type of probability. [Some notions of probability are can be found here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations) Perhaps you mean the question to be posed in the context of Bayesian logic, and perhaps not. **But I feel what you are asking is not 'how likely' so much as 'how strong and cogent' is the argument.** In other words, you want to assess how good the argument is in terms of its reason and consistency with experience, so I'll attempt to answer from there.

**The notion of "tyranny of quantifiable" to me seems to put the horse before the cart.** It alludes to the same problem raised by [Hardin's *Tragedy of the Commons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) where a person's self interest tends to ignore the impact of their behavior on others. In economics, this called [externalizing costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externality). I measure my personal gain, and take advantage of shared resources, but that impact gets ignored. US companies who profit from the sale of a chemical, but dump waste into the community is a simple example.

Here's the thing. **It's not that such things CANNOT be measured. It's that those things are CHOSEN not to be measured.** Anything can be operationalized and measured, even highly subjective experiences like love and pain. (Whether or not it is done meaningfully is a separate discussion.) That a company would choose to ignore the damage to the environment is not about metrics; it's about the incentive to apply metrics. The moment a company is responsible for measuring the damage to the environment, they have to take financial responsibility which is a cost. They would rather pretend it cannot be measured to externalize (not pay for) the cost.

**So "the tyranny of the quantifiable" seems to me to buy into a claim that holds no water.** That damage to the public good, for instance, cannot be measured. That seems to me to play into the hands of the claims of those who prefer to externalize costs. "The tyranny of the quantifiable" seems to give credence to the excuse making. While it is true, it is not as intuitive to quantify damage in more abstract ways, that's a failure of imagination, and not an exclusion of possibility. It's a typical exercise for public interest think tanks and research groups to quantify such damages usually in the form of medical bills, tax expenditures, and even impact on quality of life which is also quantifiable. (Again, arguments of how to quantify meaningfully is a separate issue.)

**Therefore the "tyranny of the quantifiable" seems to be a misconception about the psychology of humans considering that humans CAN quantify but CHOOSE not to.**

Answer (score 1):

I am not in the least prepared to accept that what can be quantified almost always takes precedent over what cannot. It seems to me to be the type of claim that sounds clever but doesn't bear serious scrutiny. For example, are we to believe that public good cannot be quantified? Are we to suppose that our inability to quantify public good is the reason why there are private profiteers?  Enjoyment and quality can certainly be quantified, and often take precedent over speed and efficiency. The entire extract you have quoted seems, IMHO, shallow and pretentious. Greed, gullibility and sort-term thinking are the important factors here, not the so-called tyranny of quantification.